# VB Just Cause 2 Save Editor

Tags: vb.net

This is a game save editor for "just cause 2" made in Visual Basic

```
Imports PackageIO

Public Class Form1
Dim Money As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Chaos As String
Dim weppart As String
Dim vpart As String
Private Sub Open_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim open As New OpenFileDialog
    open.Title = "Open JS2 GameSave"
    open.ShowDialog()
    Filepath = open.FileName
    ReadFile()
End Sub
Private Sub ReadFile()
    Try
        Dim Reader As New PackageIO.Reader(Filepath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Reader.Position = 236068
        Money = Reader.Position
        TextBox1.Text = Reader.ReadInt32

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub ReadFile2()
    Try
        Dim Reader As New PackageIO.Reader(Filepath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Reader.Position = 8
        Chaos = Reader.Position
        TextBox2.Text = Reader.ReadInt32

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub ReadFile3()
    Try
        Dim Reader As New PackageIO.Reader(Filepath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Reader.Position = 236038
        weppart = Reader.Position
        TextBox3.Text = Reader.ReadInt32

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub ReadFile4()
    Try
        Dim Reader As New PackageIO.Reader(Filepath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Reader.Position = 236058
        vpart = Reader.Position
        TextBox4.Text = Reader.ReadInt32

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub WriteFile()
    Try
        Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(Filepath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Writer.Position = Money
        Writer.WriteInt32(TextBox1.Text)
        MsgBox("Modded Succesfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub WriteFile2()
    Try
        Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(Filepath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Writer.Position = Chaos
        Writer.WriteInt32(TextBox2.Text)
        MsgBox("Modded Succesfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub WriteFile3()
    Try
        Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(Filepath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Writer.Position = weppart
        Writer.WriteInt32(TextBox3.Text)
        MsgBox("Modded Succesfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub WriteFile4()
    Try
        Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(Filepath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Writer.Position = vpart
        Writer.WriteInt32(TextBox4.Text)
        MsgBox("Modded Succesfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub WriteFiles()
    WriteFile()
    WriteFile2()
    WriteFile3()
    WriteFile4()
End Sub

Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WriteFiles()
End Sub

End Class
```

Basically it opens 4 save windows total when i hit save. I only want it to pop up once. This is a game save editor for "just cause 2" made in Visual Basic

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question...

Comment: Stop calling it four times.  Call it only once after you're done.  Oooh, magic!

Comment: i already told u about my problem ... it clearly says "i only want it to pop up once"

Comment: You need to turn on Option Strict; each of those xxxFileN methods could be combined into one - as is, each one has its own annoying little MsgBox

Answer (score 0):

What does *"it opens 4 save windows"* mean? Do you mean that you see the Open file dialog 4 times?  Or do you mean you see the message *"Modded Succesfully"* four times?  If the latter, it is because you are calling it 4 times, in each of your `WriteFileN` methods.  Just remove the `MsgBox` call from each of the write methods and add it once after you call all of them:

```
Private Sub WriteFiles()
    WriteFile()
    WriteFile2()
    WriteFile3()
    WriteFile4()
    MsgBox("Modded Succesfully")     '<--- Only place where this should be
End Sub
```